# How to determine the location of a Cloud WebRole on Harddisk?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-configuration

After creating a Azure Project within my silverlight app and adding the existing service as a "Add Web Role Project in Solution" I can run my silverlight app hosted in the Cloud and run it successfully locally.

I would like to use the SDK Toolkit instead of Visual Studio to create a package from the webrole. But what is the correct path to the WebRole?

Comment: It seems like the question should be, "How do I package and deploy to azure without Visual Studio?".  Not sure you need what you're asking for to accomplish that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to create a package, you shouldn't need to know where your local role runs.  You should only need the service definition file and the binaries/files.

See the cspack cmdline:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433133.aspx

You can also use msbuild to create a package:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh301088.aspx

Also, this is a good starting point:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433055.aspx

Let me know if I mis-understood what you're trying to ultimately accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I think I didn't ask the question properly and would have to start again in more detail.  Thank for the links, it is useful for another step of my problem.